# Image upload after jquery validation using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I am trying to upload the image using AJAX after jquery validation but it's not working. Jquery validation is working in case field is empty. After filling all the fields and clicked on submit button then my page refreshed. It's not calling the controller.

Would you help me out?

```
$("#primary").validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            required: true,
            alphabets: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        last_name: {
            alphabets: true            
        },
        profile_pic: {
            extension: "png|jpeg|jpg|gif"                      
        },
    },

    messages: {
        profile_pic: {
            extension: "Only PNG , JPEG , JPG, GIF File Allowed",
        },  
    },

    submitHandler: function(form)
    {
      var formData = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + "/AddMember/addMembers",
                type: 'POST',
                //data: $('#primary').serialize(),
                data:formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) 
         {                  
            if (data.error == "true")
            {           
             //success message
            } 
          else {
               //error message
               }
          }

            });
    }

});
```

Controller code

```
    $config=['upload_path'   =>'./uploads/images',
             'allowed_types' =>'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
             'file_name'     =>uniqid().time().date("dmy")
             ]; 
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic'))
            {
            $profile_pic_set = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            }
            else{$profile_pic_set = "";//set empty value if user not uploading any image
 }
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $data = array(
                  'first_name'  =>  trim($this->input->post('first_name')),
                  'last_name'   =>  trim($this->input->post('last_name')),
                  'profile_pic' =>  $profile_pic_set
                   );   
                    print_r($data); //here I am getting profile_pic empty.
```

**html**

```
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('','id="primary"'); ?>
              <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control"  placeholder="First Name">
              <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control"  placeholder="Last Name">
<input type="file" name="profile_pic" id="file_upload">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn_new">Submit</button>
              <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: There are no such rules in the jQuery Validate plugin called `filesize` or `alphabets`.  If these are custom rules, then you should let us know and show the code.

Comment: Oh!. Sorry for my bad. I will remove it

Comment: If the page is refreshing then your JavaScript is likely not working due to an error.  Check your browser's JavaScript console for errors.  Check the setting that saves console error messages between screen refreshes.

Comment: You have not shown enough code to reproduce anything.  You tagged the question with `HTML5` but it has nothing to do with HTML.  Where is the relevant HTML markup of the form?  For uploading files, you need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on the `form`.

Comment: @Sparky, Yes that's correct,I am using enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form tag. I am getting the error TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.[Learn More]  I am getting the error in             var formData = new FormData(this); this line

Comment: Your problem is inside `FormData(this)`.  The `this` is the validator itself, not the form object.  The form object is the `form` argument that is passed into the `submitHandler`.

Comment: Should be `FormData(form)`.  See answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/35322901/594235

Comment: @Sparky, Yes, before I tried form but I was getting an error in console TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.[Learn More]

Comment: So why not google that instead?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390646/594235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement*

Your problem is inside `FormData(this)`. The `this` represents the validator itself, not the form object. The form object is represented by the `form` argument that is passed into the `submitHandler`.

So `FormData()` should contain the `form` argument.

Also, need to set the Ajax `processData` and `contentType` parameters to `false`...

```
submitHandler: function(form){
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + "/AddMember/addMembers",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData, 
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        ....
```

**References**:

[Send image with ajax , using jquery validator on submitHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35322901/594235)

> *TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData*

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390646/594235